# How to change tab items position in tabcontrol in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol

I wanna change my sub tabcontrol items' position like shown below.

```
 -------------------------------------------------------
 |                                                     |
 |                  TabItem2      TabeItem3            |
 |  TabItem1        -----------------------------------|
 |                  TabItem2.1      TabItem2.2         |
 |-----------------------------------------------------|
```

I have 2 tabcontrols, the first one contains TabItem1,TabItem2,TabItem3 and th second contains TabItem2.1 and TabItem2.2
what i want is to move the second tabcontrol position.

Help please!

Comment: what is TabItem 2.1 and 2.2, are those different Tabs all together or are they the content of them?

Comment: it's another tabcontrol while clicking on tabitem2

Comment: A tab control within the the original tabItem?

Answer (score 0):

To clarify what you're asking, do you want this behavior?

3 (say) tabs, but two of them "share" a child tabControl:

[image]